# Determine if $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{n^2}$ converges uniformly on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I proved that $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $[0,1]$ on the previous problem. In that case I could easily show that $$\forall \epsilon>0, |f_n(x) - f(x)| = |\frac{x}{n^2} - 0| < \epsilon \quad\forall n > N = \frac{1} {\sqrt{\epsilon}}$$ where I could find $N$ by manipulating inequality $\frac{x}{n^2} < \epsilon$ since I knew $x=1$ at maximum.

With the interval $[0, \infty)$, I can't use that same argument because $x \ne 1$ at maximum? How would I go about this? I am assuming $f_n$ converges to 0 uniformly in this new interval as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But it doesn't converge uniformly on that interval. Note that there is no $N\in\mathbb N$ such that the set$$\left\{\bigl\lvert f_n(x)-0\bigr\rvert\,\middle|\,x\in[0,\infty)\right\}$$is bounded. In particular, t is not true that there is some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that$$n\geqslant N\implies\bigl(\forall x\in[0,\infty)\bigr):\bigl\lvert f_n(x)-0\bigr\rvert<1.$$

Comment: but again we are using $f(x) = 0 \forall x \in [0, \infty)$ in the definition of uniform convergence. Don't I have to use a general $f(x)$, not a single case of $f(x)$? I'm not sure how the proof should look tbh

Comment: No need to do that, because when a sequence of functions converges uniformly to a function, then it also converges pointwise to that function. And you already know that your sequence of functions converges pointwise to the null function!

Comment: So Proof would be like 1. Show that $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f(x) = 0 \forall x \in [0, \infty)$ 2. Consider say $f_n(n^2)$, which is clearly not uniformly convergent at points $x = n^2$

Comment: My proof is different. I prove that the convergence is not uniform by the definition of uniform convergence.

Comment: oh yes, sorry, I was looking at the other answerer's hint. But I think I get the general idea, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Consider $f_n(n^2).\,\,$

Comment: In that case, $\forall \epsilon > 0, |f_n(n^2) - f(x)| = 1 > \epsilon \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N$, and wouldn't converge uniformly. However, isn't this assuming $f_n$ converges pointwise to a specific $f(x)$ (in this case 0 everywhere)? Or do I have to show that $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f(x) = 0 \forall x$ first?

Comment: A good hint  $(+1)$

Comment: @MinYoungKim The value at this particular point implies that the supremum of the difference over the interval is at least $1$ (in fact, it is infinite!), so convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Clearly $f_n\to 0$ pointwise. If $f_n$ converged uniformly, it would have to converge to $0$ uniformly.